# Split String and Count Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, split, timestamp, teradata

I would like to split column 'ASPCT_VLU_NM' and count of occurrences of the timestamps in a given time frame.
For example return the ID which have more than 3 occurrence in between *1537160520286* and *1537190520286*.

In the example below those are the timestamps :
[image: The values which should be extracted from the column]

[image: The data in Teradata]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Teradata 14 or later, then you may take advantage of the `STRTOK` function here:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    CAST(STRTOK(ASPCT_VLU_NM, ',', 4) AS BIGINT) BETWEEN 1537160520286 AND 1537190520286
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 3;
```

Note: You may want to give serious consideration to changing your table design, in particular to *not* storing CSV data in the `ASPCT_VLU_NM` column.  Instead, get each CSV value into a separate row/column.

Comment: I get error :  [SQLState 22003] Numeric overflow occurred during computation.

Comment: @userit1985 Try casting to double precision instead to accommodate the size of the UNIX timestamps.

Comment: @userit1985: Use a BIGINT instead. Or no cast at all as all those timestamps will have the same length Unix and can be compared as strings. And just in case there's bad data `TRYCAST` instead of `CAST` which returns NULL instead of an error.

Comment: @dnoeth I also would like to just use between with text, but the thing is that there is no guarantee that all UNIX timestamps would have the same width.

Comment: At least for all vaues after 2001-09-09 03:46:41 (up to the year 2286) the length will be the same :-)